# Issue while installing Postal (Address Parser ) package of python

Tags: python-3.x, msys2, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am trying to install postal package using

```
pip install postal
```

I am following the steps mentioned in link
https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal#installation-windows

I have installed Visual Studio 2019 C++ Build Tools, MSYS2 and performed the step

```
git clone https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal
cd libpostal
cp -rf windows/* ./
./bootstrap.sh
./configure --datadir=[...some dir with a few GB of space...]
make -j4
make install
```

Still I am not able to install postal package using `pip install postal`

Getting below logs while installing postal package.

```
(base) C:\Users\Praveen>pip install postal
Collecting postal
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/f7/69ca5d374077e23aa9a51ecd4031222ca9dfb7d19c95d7691f024e2e27ef/postal-1.1.8.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from postal) (1.12.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: postal
  Building wheel for postal (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Praveen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9sens8xe\\postal\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Praveen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9sens8xe\\postal\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-e6vpt_0y' --python-tag cp37
       cwd: C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9sens8xe\postal\
  Complete output (35 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
  copying postal\dedupe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
  copying postal\expand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
  copying postal\near_dupe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
  copying postal\normalize.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
  copying postal\parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
  copying postal\tokenize.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
  copying postal\token_types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
  copying postal\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\tests
  copying postal\tests\test_expand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\tests
  copying postal\tests\test_parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\tests
  copying postal\tests\_test_near_dupes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\tests
  copying postal\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\tests
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\utils
  copying postal\utils\encoding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\utils
  copying postal\utils\enum.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\utils
  copying postal\utils\omitted.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\utils
  copying postal\utils\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\utils
  copying postal\pyutils.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
  running build_ext
  building 'postal._expand' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\postal
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/local/include -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpostal/pyexpand.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\postal/pyexpand.obj -std=c99
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c99'
  pyexpand.c
  postal/pyexpand.c(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libpostal/libpostal.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.20.27508\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for postal
  Running setup.py clean for postal
Failed to build postal
Installing collected packages: postal
  Running setup.py install for postal ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Praveen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9sens8xe\\postal\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Praveen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9sens8xe\\postal\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-k92kr5uk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9sens8xe\postal\
    Complete output (35 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
    copying postal\dedupe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
    copying postal\expand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
    copying postal\near_dupe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
    copying postal\normalize.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
    copying postal\parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
    copying postal\tokenize.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
    copying postal\token_types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
    copying postal\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\tests
    copying postal\tests\test_expand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\tests
    copying postal\tests\test_parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\tests
    copying postal\tests\_test_near_dupes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\tests
    copying postal\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\tests
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\utils
    copying postal\utils\encoding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\utils
    copying postal\utils\enum.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\utils
    copying postal\utils\omitted.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\utils
    copying postal\utils\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal\utils
    copying postal\pyutils.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\postal
    running build_ext
    building 'postal._expand' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\postal
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/local/include -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include -IC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpostal/pyexpand.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\postal/pyexpand.obj -std=c99
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c99'
    pyexpand.c
    postal/pyexpand.c(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libpostal/libpostal.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.20.27508\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Praveen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9sens8xe\\postal\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Praveen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9sens8xe\\postal\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-k92kr5uk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time, libpostal fails in windows python bindings, so I have got a new python package that bundled the libpostal and using the python package, it can be used.

Here is the package called [pypostalwin](https://github.com/selva221724/pypostalwin)

Follow the ReadMe instructions and enjoy using libpostal from python

Answer (score 7):

Try the following solution. I am running this in WSL.

Changes

1. Navigate to cd~ directory before all commands.
2. Use 'sudo' before make.

```
cd~
git clone https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal
cd libpostal
./bootstrap.sh
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Then run
`pip install postal`

Also `pip install nose` prior to importing and running the **postal** library.